# Create multiple VMs in Azure with different nic with Terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, cloud, terraform-provider-azure

I need to create two vm's which have different nic's. This is my code, but I have an error and I don't know why:

```
# Create network interface
resource "azurerm_network_interface" "my_nic" {
  for_each = toset(var.nics)
  name = each.key
  location            = "northeurope"
  resource_group_name = "webapp"

  ip_configuration {
    name                          = "my_nic_configuration"
    subnet_id                     = data.azurerm_subnet.my_subnet.id
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
  }
}
```

```
# Create VM
resource "azurerm_linux_virtual_machine" "my_vm" {
  #count                 = 2 #update
  for_each = toset(var.instances)
  name = each.key
  resource_group_name   = var.resource_group_name
  location              = var.location
  size                  = "Standard_F4s_v2"
  network_interface_ids = [azurerm_network_interface.my_nic[each.key].id]
```

The error:

```txt
│ Error: Invalid index
│ 
│   on main.tf line 79, in resource "azurerm_linux_virtual_machine" "my_vm":
│   79:   network_interface_ids = [azurerm_network_interface.my_nic[each.key].id]
│     ├────────────────
│     │ azurerm_network_interface.my_nic is object with 2 attributes
│     │ each.key is "vm01, vm02"
│ 
│ The given key does not identify an element in this collection value.
```

Answer (score 2):

You did not provide the code for `var.instances` or `var.nics` ...

But from the error you are getting we can assume that in the variables the keys do not match, you can do what you are trying in that same way with two variables, but I would suggest just using one, see my sample code below

```
variable "instances" {
  type = any
  default = {
    "vm1" = {
      "nic_name" = "abc"
    }
    "vm2" = {
      "nic_name" = "def"
    }
  }
}

resource "azurerm_network_interface" "my_nic" {
  for_each = var.instances
  name     = each.value.nic_name
  location = "northeurope"
  ...
}

resource "azurerm_linux_virtual_machine" "my_vm" {
  for_each = var.instances
  name     = each.key
  ...
  network_interface_ids = [azurerm_network_interface.my_nic[each.value.nic_name].id]
}
```

You can see now the `instances` is a bit more complex map object, for this example I'm keeping it simple, we only have one property there `nic_name` but with this map object you can add as many properties as you need there to suit your needs.